# Generating the App.Config file for a Managed Windows Service using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

My next project is going to be using Windows Communication Foundation to host Managed Windows Services, so I have been trying to follow a HOWTO on msdn - [How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx). Sounds like a perfect match.

All was well until it started mentioning an App.Config file but without outlining how it got generated in the first place.

As I have posted there, there is probably some assumed prior knowledge (perhaps from another tutorial), but I couldn't find the answer after some searching.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about item #5?  The app.config file is generated by you.  You can add the item to your project in VS.NET by right clicking on the project and selecting to add a new config file.  Then you can add the section as indicated by the step.